# How to delete a line from a file containing sh extension?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm using Ubuntu. I have an `fileName.sh` file containing 1000 lines and I have to delete the `399 number` line is this command is sufficient for the deleting the line.

Command:- `sed -i '399d' test.sh`

Is there any need to change in this command? And can you please give me more suggestions to delete the line from a file?

Comment: Have you tried running the command and verifying the result manually ? What was the result ?

Comment: yes I tried this command in result it will delete the line from the file @SorenA

Comment: So why the question ?

Comment: IMHO deleting by line number is dangerous, if there is any change in what produces the target file you'll be deleting the wrong line. Deleting by pattern woul be a bit safer (though still dangerous if done on a script).

Comment: @xenoid whatever method you do it all has the same risk. If 1 of the actual arguments is "is has to be line 399" I do not see anything wrong. I would assume someone would 1st verify it is indeed line 399.

Comment: Don't backups work any more?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! If you have some working code you want others to review, please use [codereview.se].

Comment: @SorenA Question I posted because if I'm doing something wrong in this command then you guys guide me that my query is wrong. I also don't is there any impact of this command on other files. There is also a case like it will done what I want but on other side it will effect the other files that's why

Comment: @xenoid Can you tell me the better method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better (but stiull unsafe) to remove the line using its contents than using a line number. If you want to delete a line whose contents are known:

```
sed -i /{contents}/d in.sh
```

Another solution is to use grep -v:

```
grep -v '{contents}' <in.sh >out.sh
```

In both cases {contents} is a regexp that matches the contents you want to remove, knowing that strings with only letters and numbers and a few select special characters are regular expressions for themselves, so:

```
sed -i /somefile/d in.sh
grep -v 'somefile' <in.sh >out.sh
```

will remove any line containing `somefile` from the input. But keep in mind that they could also match more things (for instance `somefile2` would also be matched) unless you start using more complete regexps, for instance using `^{contents}$` to match lines that are exactly `{contents}`, excluding those that contain `{contents}` and additional things.

Comment: @catter, please also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). No need to hurry, though. Just take your time.